# Data from data frame to corpus in R

Tags: r, dataframe, corpus

I need to get data from a data frame that I have to a corpus, but I get an error "Error in VCorpus(DataframeSource(df)) : could not find function "VCorpus""

Do you have an idea why?

thank you,

```
setwd("C:/Users/hart/Desktop/1")

DATA.df <- read.csv("Sentiment180_2000.csv")

library(dplyr)

df2 <- subset(DATA.df, select = c(6))

df <- data.frame(txt = df2)
df <- data.frame(doc_id=seq(1:nrow(df)),text=df$Text)
corpus <- VCorpus(DataframeSource(df))
```

Comment: Does `library(tm)` run fine?

Answer (score 0):

```
install.packages("lavaan")
```

should get you going.